# MAX Function to select multiple values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I am using MYSQL to get the maximum number of students a TA has. With this query I get all the TA's and the number of students of each TA

```
SELECT TA.Name as Name, COUNT(Lecture.Student) AS studentcount 
FROM TA 
JOIN Lecture 
WHERE TA.TA_PUID = Lecture.TA 
GROUP BY TA.Name
ORDER BY studentcount DESC;
```

My output is this

```
David    2 
Justin   2
Matt     2
Jennifer 1
Hannah   1
Timothy  1
Bob      1
```

I want to get only the TA's with the max value of students. How can I accomplish this? In this case I want my output to be

```
David  2 
Justin 2
Matt   2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to MySQL 8, you'll have to do something like this:

```
SELECT TA.Name as Name, COUNT(Lecture.Student) AS studentcount 
FROM TA INNER JOIN Lecture ON TA.TA_PUID = Lecture.TA 
GROUP BY TA.Name
HAVING studentCount = (
   SELECT COUNT(Student) AS studentcount 
   FROM Lecture
   GROUP BY TA
   ORDER BY studentcount DESC
   LIMIT 1
);
```

If you are using MySQL 8+, the **windowing functions** and **common table expressions** are definitely the first choice though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rank()`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT TA.Name as Name, COUNT(*) AS studentcount,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM TA JOIN
           Lecture l
           ON TA.TA_PUID = l.TA
      GROUP BY TA.Name
    ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Note that `JOIN` should be followed by an `ON` clause rather than a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the version of MySQL. In MySQL 8.x you can use a CTE (Common Table Expression) to pre-compute the values. Then, filtering is easy.

For example:

```
with
a as (
  SELECT TA.Name as Name, COUNT(Lecture.Student) AS studentcount 
  FROM TA 
  JOIN Lecture 
  WHERE TA.TA_PUID = Lecture.TA 
  GROUP BY TA.Name
)
select * from a where studentcount = (select max(studentcount) from a)
```